# Magento : How to set product type as 'Simple product' when adding new product? OR how to change the product type from virtual to simple?

Tags: product, catalog, simple-product, virtual-products

Currently, when I am adding new product its product_type is set to 'Virtual'.

I am adding simple product as shown in below image.

Why this is happening while adding the product of type simple.

[image]

Comment: Add some weight in the virtual product it automatically convert to simple product.

Comment: Your suggestion is right amit.. but I am not able to add weight field while adding new product.

Comment: why? there is a field called `weight` you just need to put the value there.